# Self built pc, graphics card issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Built this pc over summer and it's *mostly* working. I'm pretty sure this problem is with the graphics card.

- I'm limited to one display at a time and only one resolution is possible.
- I've attempted changing the resolution via gui and commandline (xrandr) but only one option is available.
- The two monitors are connected by vga and dvi. The VGA monitor is stuck at 1024 * 768 (4:3) and the dvi monitor is stuck at 1600 * 1200 (4:3)
- Recently I started the computer up using the dvi monitor and then switched over to the vga monitor. This time, the resolution was stuck at 1600 * 1200. Again, there was no other options available. When I turned the computer on again next, the vga was back to 1024 * 768.
- graphics card is an nvidi gtx1050ti. CPU is an AMD ryzen 7 5700x. I'm assuming this is the source of the issue but i don't really know.
- I'm running ubuntu 23.04 and proprietary nvidia driver 535

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: nvidia x-server settings

[nvidia-settings Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPiQJ.png)

[Application profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqxnX.png)

EDIT 2: It appears the nvidia x-server driver isn't working, though reinstalling only caused more problems.

Comment: Are you using X or Wayland? What do you see in the Nvidia X Server Settings app? Is the Nvidia driver really working?  I have the same graphics card BTW.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell whether the driver is working. System settings graphics field reads "software rendering"
Using X11. X server settings has "Application Profiles" and "nvidia-settings Configuration", I don't really know how to use the application profiles and the settings are about five options, none of which look helpful. Will update the original post with screenshots

Comment: The "system information" tab in the Nvidia Settings app is probably the most informative. It shows the driver version, etc. If you aren't able to call that system information tab up, the driver probably isn't working. Mine looks like this https://i.imgur.com/OUFo7sg.png

Comment: ok yeah it looks like the driver isn't working then. I'm reinstalling it now, we'll see if it helps

Comment: Have you checked for any firmware updates for your motherboard?

Comment: So I reinstalled the nvidia driver and... now i can't use the internet. As far as I can tell, my realtek driver got uninstalled or messed with. Writing this using my install usb because when I attempted to reinstall the realtek driver I couldn't because *make* wasn't installed (maybe a new development but I hadn't used it before so idk). And I certainly couldn't do anything about that without internet. I ran into another problem trying to install make (by downloading it onto my phone) though I gave up at that point. Seems I'll need to reinstall Ubuntu to sort out this issue

Comment: I'm using the latest non-beta firmware (version 4.30). Quite cautious about trying a newer one after the realtek debacle (see above)